# Operator of arity 3 in Prolog

Tags: prolog, operators

In Prolog, how can I define the operator "relation" to work as a relation/3 predicate? For example:

`relation a b c.`

and produce it:

`relation(a, b, c).`

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, operators are not relations, nor are they predicates. Operators are a syntactical feature, they are there just to help us save on typing parentheses:

```
:- op(250,xfy,#).
```

and then

```
4 ?- X = 2#3#5, write_canonical(X).
#(2,#(3,5))
X = 2#3#5.
```

Now you can define a predicate that will deal with such compound terms, as you like. This is of course not much different than

```
5 ?- X=[2,3|5], write_canonical(X).
'.'(2,'.'(3,5))
X = [2, 3|5].
```

There is no way on the syntax level to limit such nesting of the compound terms to just two levels. Your predicate which deals with them will have to discern the valid from the invalid cases.

```
7 ?- Y=2#3#5#7, write_canonical(Y).
#(2,#(3,#(5,7)))
Y = 2#3#5#7.
```

*Or,* you could use *two* non-associative operators in tandem:

```
:- op(250,xfx,#).
:- op(350,xfx,@).
```

and then

```
10 ?- X=2@3#5, write_canonical(X).
@(2,#(3,5))
X = 2@3#5.

11 ?- X=2@3#5#7, write_canonical(X).
ERROR: Syntax error: Operator priority clash
ERROR: X=2@3#
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR: 5#7, write_canonical(X) .
```